# Python near_ten function/method

Tags: python, methods

I decided to start learn Python a few days ago (as a native C++ programmer) and I've got a silly coding problem here:

> Given a non-negative number "num", return True if num is within 2 of a 
>   multiple of 10.

I've got what I'd consider a pretty ad-hoc solution and I'm hoping an experienced python programmer can give me a cleaner solution. Thanks in advance!

My solution:

```
def near_ten(num):
    return abs(num%10) in [0,1,2,8,9]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "within 2 of a multiple of 10"?

Comment: @Allen 8,9,10,11,12 are all within 2 of a multiple of 10 as well as 18,19,20,21,22; for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty neat! I'd probably use `abs(..)` around `num` , though. And I might use a set instead of a list -- it doesn't make much difference but it sort of slightly improves readability in my opinion.

```
def near_ten(num):
    return abs(num)%10 in {0, 1, 2, 8, 9}
```

Note that I prefer the above solution with a comment to the solution below.

```
def near_ten(num):
    return abs(abs(num)%10 - 10) <= 2
```

Comment: The second one will not work but I appreciate your feedback on my solution

Comment: I decided to change my code to your modification on my code. I wrote it up too quickly to consider those aesthetic changes. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try following solution.

```
def near_ten(num):

    return not(2 < (num % 10) < 8)
```

Comment: Here you don't need to do abs. And searching in list is very much costlier in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
def near_ten(num):
    return abs(num%10 - 10) <= 2
```

---

**Update:** Added another check to make it work, although now it is less readable

```
def near_ten(num):
    return num%10 <=2 or abs(num%10 - 10) <= 2
```

Comment: This is still no good, you're gonna get numbers like -8 and -9 in some cases (absolute value is 8 and 9)

Answer (score 0):

```
#not sure if this is any better than your solution.
def near_ten(num):
    return (abs(num)+2)%10//5==0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `round` function takes a precision argument which specifies the number of decimal places, however this can be negative to round to multiples of ten. For example:

```
>>> round(38, -1)
40.0
>>> round(41, -1)
40.0
```

So you could use something like:

```
>>> def near_ten(num):
...     return abs(num - round(num, -1)) <= 2
...
>>> near_ten(0)
True
>>> near_ten(1)
True
>>> near_ten(2)
True
>>> near_ten(3)
False
>>> near_ten(7)
False
>>> near_ten(8)
True
>>> near_ten(9)
True
>>> near_ten(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def near_ten(num):
  nums = [ num-2, num-1, num, num+1, num+2]
  for n in nums:
      if n % 10 == 0:
            return True
  else:
       return False
```

Comment: hi, please consider explaining your code or solution. Only code answers are seen as low quality

Comment: Thank I will do that.