# near_ten() appears to have a bug on Codingbat

Tags: python, list, function, set, modulo

Codingbat has a practice question Under Logic-1, Python. It's called near_10.

> Given a non-negative number "num", return True if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10. Note: (a % b) is the remainder of dividing a by b, so (7 % 5) is 2

The solution on one user's GitHub is  given as

```
def near_ten(num):
  
  within = num%((num/10)*10) if num >= 10 else num
  return within in [8,9,0,1,2]
```

This is accepted as the correct answer for all examples contained in the code-check table

[image]

However, in a Jupyter Notebook, when I pass the False examples from the above table in the function near_ten() I get varying outcomes

[image]

I searched here on S.O. and found an answer by UltraInstinct that worked
[Python near_ten function/method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601461/python-near-ten-function-method)

[image]

Comment: Yeah that solution is nonsense, `10 * (num / 10)` does nothing but return `num` as a `float`. Since `num` is guaranteed to be non-negative, you actually only need `num % 10`.

Comment: "`It is more an issue of a website having a faulty code check for a solution which beginning coders use to train for technical interviews. This question thereby helps the development community and should be reopened in my opinion.`" - This is still not appropriate for SO, report the bug to Codingbat itself, we cannot do anything about the bug on their site, can we?

Comment: I contacted Codingbat.  New programmers deserve a heads up on the issue. Most of them search SO primarily. So your opinion that it is not appropriate is just that, your opinion @h4z3

Comment: You're right they go to SO, but as I pointed out, it's not a place to report a problem from a different website + there's no really question in there, you just state "there's an error" and that's it

Comment: The issue is more than merely a typo in an answer on a GitHub repo, as the reason for closing this question would suggest. It can be reproduced anytime, merely by attempting the Codingbat exercise. So the two reasons for closing this question are erroneous. It is an issue of the website having a faulty code-check on a solution which beginning coders use to train for technical interviews. I've contacted Codingbat and received no response.  This question thereby helps the development community and should be reopened in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you provided is indeed false and doesn't work in the slightest. Take a look at the first term `((num/10)*10)`: this evaluates to just `num`. This means for all integers greater than 9 your result is `num % num` which will always be 0. As well, because this code uses normal division it will convert all terms to floats.

The second solution you provided is correct since all you need is the first no-decimal digit.